# Error login JAVA

Tags: java, authentication, error-handling, hashset

while trying to add an user to my login list, which is a text file, I always get an error that I absolutely don't understand.

My code basically do 2 things. First it compare the username and password given by the user to see if he is already present to the login list (text file). Second he let the user can sign up, in other word added in the login list.

Now I'm trying to add a score system, where for each user there is the number of victories and defeats for games that I will create later.

Here is my code:

**Main**

```
package boitedejeux;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoiteDeJeux {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UsernameException, PasswordException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username;
        String password;
        System.out.println("Enter your username:");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your password:");
        password = input.nextLine();
        UserList test = new UserList();
        test.inscription(username, password);
    }

}
```

**User**

```
package boitedejeux;

import java.util.Objects;

public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Score ps;

    public User(String username, String password, int hangmanVictory, int hangmanDefeat) throws UsernameException, PasswordException {
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur ne soit pas vide.
        if (username.length() == 0 || username.length() == 1) {
            throw new UsernameException("The username must contain at least two elements.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur ne soit pas vide.
        if (username.length() == 0 || username.length() == 1) {
            throw new UsernameException("The username must contain at least two elements.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur doit commencer par une majuscule.
        if (username.charAt(0) > 'Z' || username.charAt(0) < 'A') {
            throw new UsernameException("The username must begin with an uppercase.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur ne doit contenir que des minuscules et des chiffres.
        for (int i = 1; i < username.length(); i++) {
            if ((username.charAt(i) > 'z' || username.charAt(i) < 'a') && (username.charAt(i) > '9' || username.charAt(i) < '0')) {
                throw new UsernameException("The username must contain only lowercase and numbers after the first element.");
            }
        }
        // On vérifie que le vérifie que le mot de passe de l'utilisateur ne soit pas vide.
        if (password.length() == 0 || password.length() == 1) {
            throw new PasswordException("The password contain at least two elements.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le mot de passe de l'utilisateur doit commencer par une majuscule.
        if (password.charAt(0) > 'Z' || password.charAt(0) < 'A') {
            throw new PasswordException("The password must begin with an uppercase.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le mot de passe de l'utilisateur ne doit contenir que des minuscules et des chiffres.
        for (int i = 1; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if ((password.charAt(i) > 'z' || password.charAt(i) < 'a') && (password.charAt(i) > '9' || password.charAt(i) < '0')) {
                throw new PasswordException("The password must contain only lowercase and numbers after the first element.");
            }
        }
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.ps = new Score(hangmanVictory, hangmanDefeat);
    }

    //Renvoie le pseudo de l'utilisateur.
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    //Renvoie le mot de passe de l'utilisateur.
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof User) {
            return ((User) o).username.equals(username);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.username);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

**UserList**

```
package boitedejeux;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserList {

    private HashSet<User> loginList;

    //Initialise une liste vide et la remplie à partir d'un fichier texte.
    public UserList() throws UsernameException, PasswordException {
        Scanner scan;
        loginList = new HashSet();
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("src/boitedejeux/Logins.txt"));
            String ligne = scan.nextLine();
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                ligne = scan.nextLine();
                String[] res = ligne.split(", ");
                loginList.add(new User(res[0], (res[1]), Integer.parseInt(res[2]), Integer.parseInt(res[3])));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    // Vérifie que la loginList soit bien initialisé.
    //Puis l'a parcours en vérifiant que le nom d'uttilisateur et le mot de passe correspondent à un présent dans la liste. Si présent renvoie "True" sinon "False".
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        if (null == loginList) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The login list isn't initialised");
        }

        return loginList.stream()
                .filter(usern -> usern.getUsername().equals(username))
                .filter(passw -> passw.getPassword().equals(password))
                .findFirst()
                .isPresent();
    }

    //Ajoute un joueur dans le fichier texte.
    public void inscription(String username, String password) throws IOException, UsernameException, PasswordException {
        // On vérifie que le nom d'utilisateur n'existe déjà pas.

        Iterator<User> it = loginList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            User u = (User) it.next();
            if (username.equals(u)) {
                throw new UsernameException("This username already exist.");
            }
        }
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur ne soit pas vide.
        if (username.length() == 0 || username.length() == 1) {
            throw new UsernameException("The username must contain at least two elements.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur doit commencer par une majuscule.
        if (username.charAt(0) > 'Z' || username.charAt(0) < 'A') {
            throw new UsernameException("The username must begin with an uppercase.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le nom de l'utilisateur ne doit contenir que des minuscules et des chiffres.
        for (int i = 1; i < username.length(); i++) {
            if ((username.charAt(i) > 'z' || password.charAt(i) < 'a') && (username.charAt(i) > '9' || username.charAt(i) < '0')) {
                throw new UsernameException("The username must contain only lowercase and numbers after the first element.");
            }
        }
        // On vérifie que le mot de passe de l'utilisateur ne soit pas vide.
        if (password.length() == 0 || username.length() == 1) {
            throw new PasswordException("The password must contain at least two elements.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le mot de passe de l'utilisateur doit commencer par une majuscule.
        if (password.charAt(0) > 'Z' || password.charAt(0) < 'A') {
            throw new PasswordException("The password must begin with an uppercase.");
        }
        // On vérifie que le mot de passe de l'utilisateur ne doit contenir que des minuscules et des chiffres.
        for (int i = 1; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if ((password.charAt(i) > 'z' || password.charAt(i) < 'a') && (password.charAt(i) > '9' || password.charAt(i) < '0')) {
                throw new PasswordException("The password must contain only lowercase and numbers after the first element.");
            }
            Writer output;
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/boitedejeux/Logins.txt", true));
            output.append("\n" + username + ", " + password+", 0, 0");
            output.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Score**

```
package boitedejeux;

public class Score {

    private int victory;
    private int defeat;

    public Score(int victory, int defeat) {
        this.victory = victory;
        this.defeat = defeat;
    }

}
```

**Login.txt**

```
Username, Password, 0, 0
Test, Test, 0, 0
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at boitedejeux.UserList.inscription(UserList.java:70)
    at boitedejeux.BoiteDeJeux.main(BoiteDeJeux.java:17)
C:\Users\aabdo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I don't know if it can help but the username and password that I gave where respectively: "Test2" and "Test".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((username.charAt(i) > 'z' || password.charAt(i) < 'a') && (username.charAt(i) > '9' || username.charAt(i) < '0')) {
            throw new UsernameException("The username must contain only lowercase and numbers after the first element.");
        }
```

note that the second string is password instead of username.

and this loop should start with i=0

Comment: Totally missed it, thanks a lot man, you really saved me :). Thanks to you I also see that I had another error of that type in an another line ;).